# 2 values in an if statement are not working - Rock Paper Scissors Game C#

Tags: c#, arrays

So I am in a bit of a predicament where I cannot make my if statements work correctly, they display nothing on screen, funnily enough only the top if statement works when the computer and user draw in a rock paper scissors game.

Here is my the code in the method which does not work properly:

```
         using System;
         using System.Collections.Generic;
         using System.Linq;
         using System.Text;
         using System.Threading.Tasks;

         namespace SPSProject
         {
         class Game
         {
    string compChoice;
    string playerChoice;
    string name;
    Random randy;
    public string PAPER;
    public string STONE;
    public string SCISSORS;

    static void Main()
    {
        Game myGame = new Game();  // create new Game object
        myGame.play();             // call its play method
    }
    //*******************************************************
    public Game()
    {
        randy = new Random();       // create new Random object
    }
    //*******************************************************
    public void play()
    {
        setupScreen();
        introduction();
        getPlayerChoice();
        getComputerChoice();
        drawPlayerChoice();
        printChoices();
        showResult();
        Console.ReadKey();   // wait for a key press
    }
    //********************************************************
    private void setupScreen()
    {
        Console.Title = " The Great Scissors-Paper-Stone Game";
        Console.SetWindowSize(100, 36);
        Console.SetBufferSize(100, 36);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();  // clear screen in chosen colour
    }
    //********************************************************
    private void introduction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tPlay the Scissors Paper Stone Game");
        Console.WriteLine("\t==================================");
    }
    //********************************************************
    private void getPlayerChoice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WHAT IS YOUR NAME?");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\twhat is your choice" + " " + name + "?");
        Console.Write("\tScissors Paper or Stone : ");
        playerChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        playerChoice = playerChoice.ToUpper();
    }
    //*******************************************************
    private void getComputerChoice()
    {
        int num;
        num = randy.Next(3);  // pick a random number (0, 1 or 2)

        if (num == 0)
        {
            compChoice = "SCISSORS";
        }

        if (num == 1)
        {
            compChoice = "PAPER";
        }

        if (num == 2)
        {
            compChoice = "STONE";
        }

    }
    //***************************************************
    private void printChoices()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t You picked " + playerChoice);
        Console.WriteLine("\tThe computer choice is " + compChoice);
    }
    //***************************************************
    private void showResult()
    {
        if (playerChoice == compChoice)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tA DRAW!!");
        }

        if (playerChoice == PAPER && compChoice == SCISSORS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("COMPUTER WINS AS SCISSORS BEATS PAPER");
        }

        if (playerChoice == STONE && compChoice == SCISSORS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + "WINS AS STONE BEATS SCISSORS");
        }

        if (playerChoice == SCISSORS && compChoice == PAPER)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + "WINS AS SCISSORS BEATS PAPER");
        }

        if (playerChoice == STONE && compChoice == PAPER)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name = "WINS AS STONE BEATS PAPER");
        }

        if (playerChoice == SCISSORS && compChoice == STONE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("COMPUTER WINS AS STONE BEATS SCISSORS");
        }

        if (playerChoice == PAPER && compChoice == STONE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + "WINS AS PAPER BEATS STONE");
        }

    }
    //******************************************************
    private void drawPlayerChoice()
    {
        if (playerChoice == "SCISSORS")
        {
            drawScissors(15, 10);
        }
        else if (playerChoice == "PAPER")
        {
            drawPaper(15, 10);
        }
        else if (playerChoice == "STONE")
        {
            drawStone(15, 10);
        }
    }
    //*******************************************************************
    private void drawScissors(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);   // set start position then increment y to move down
        Console.Write("     \\            /");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("      \\          /");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("       \\        /");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("        \\      /");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("         \\    /");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("          \\  /");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("           **");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("          /  \\");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("    (----/    \\----)");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("     \\  /      \\  /");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("      ==        ==");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
    }
    //**************************************************************
    private void drawStone(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);   // set start position then increment y to move down
        Console.Write("                 ___---___     ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("              .--         --.    ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("           ./   ()       .-. \\.   ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("           /   o    .   (   )  \\  ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("          / .            '-'    \\  ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("         /     ()   ()           \\ ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("        |    o           ()       | ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("        |      .--.           O   | ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("         \\ .  |    |              |  ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("          \\   `.__.'     o   .   /    ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("           `\\  o    ()         /'    ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("              `--___    ___--'    ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("                     ---         ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    //************************************************************************
    private void drawPaper(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);    // set start position then increment y to move down
        Console.Write("      .--.------------------.");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("     /      \\  \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("    /   OOO  \\                |");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("   |   OOOO   || A N D R E X | |");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("   |   OOOO   |                |");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("    \\   OOO   /                /");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("     \\      // / / / / / / / //");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("       `--'-|| | | | | | | | |");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("             \\                \\");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("              \\                \\");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("               \\                \\");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("                \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\\\");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y++);
        Console.Write("                 \\________________\\");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    //************************************************************************
    private void drawSmile()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n                    .-\"\"\"\"-.-\"\"\"\"-. ");
        Console.WriteLine("               _.'`               `'._   ");
        Console.WriteLine("            .-'  __..,.___.___.,..__  '-.   ");
        Console.WriteLine("           '-.-;` |  |    |    |  | `;-.-'   ");
        Console.WriteLine("            \\'-\\_/\\__|    |    |__/\\_/-'/   ");
        Console.WriteLine("             \\, _     '---'---'     _ ,/   ");
        Console.WriteLine("              \\'./`'.--.--.--,--.'`\\.'/   ");
        Console.WriteLine("               \\ `'-;__|__|__|__;-'` /   ");
        Console.WriteLine("                '.                 .'   ");
        Console.WriteLine("                 `'-....---....-'`    ");
    }
    //*************************************
    private void drawThumbsUp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("       _ ");
        Console.WriteLine("      ( ((  ");
        Console.WriteLine("       \\ =\\   ");
        Console.WriteLine("      __\\_ `-\\   ");
        Console.WriteLine("     (____))(  \\-----  ");
        Console.WriteLine("     (____)) _    ");
        Console.WriteLine("     (____))   ");
        Console.WriteLine("     (____))____/-----  ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    //*************************************
    private void drawThumbsDown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("       ______ ");
        Console.WriteLine("     ((____  \\-----  ");
        Console.WriteLine("     ((_____         ");
        Console.WriteLine("     ((_____      ");
        Console.WriteLine("     ((____   -----   ");
        Console.WriteLine("          /  /    ");
        Console.WriteLine("         (_((     ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

}

I tried different ways to make the if statements below the 'draw' one to work by getting rid of the two '&&' and using only one. This does nothing by the way, I can not think of any other ways to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and debugging what is happening by checking what the values actually are and stepping through the code?

Comment: Did you try to debug this? You certainly get out what conditions are failing when you use the debugegr. Btw.: I suppose all (except the first) your `if`-statements should be `else`-statements, as it´s unlikely that `playerChoice` is `PAPER` and `SCISSOR` at the same time.

Comment: What is the type of `playerChoice` and `compChoice`? Also, what values are in STONE, PAPER etc, please show their declaration (either as variables or as constants)

Comment: debugging is key

Comment: Yes, no errors show up in the output area, the code runs through perfectly fine. It is just that it does not display the outcome on screen, I have a feeling that the layout of the if statement is incorrect.

Comment: How did you define `ROCK`, `PAPER`, and `SCISSORS`? Are they enums or constants?

Comment: Are the choices strings? Could it be, that they contain "invisible" characters or maybe a space at the end or something like that? -- The logic *seems* to be okay, so my guess is, there is something wrong with the values.

Comment: Debug and see what `playerChoice` and `compChoice` are when within your method.

Comment: They have been defined at the top of the program and they are constants, also I tried else if statements but the same outcome was achieved.

Comment: We're going to need to see how you assign playerChoice and compChoice, as well as the values of PAPER/STONE/SCISSORS. Also, it looks like if the player picks Stone they can't lose.

Comment: the best strategy to rock paper scissors has been found. just find a noob dev and play their game. Do you intend to return something? (since its a  function)

Comment: paper, stone and scissors are declared as public strings right at the top of the program. Thee three variables have green lines on the bottom saying nothing has been assigned to them even though there is.

Comment: You need to show the codes, not describe them. I can't see your problem through a game of telephone.

Comment: ok, I will edit the post

Comment: You don´t need to post the entire code, just that one which is relevant to your question. In particular thumbs up and smile are unlikely to help anyone.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Speak for yourself, it made my day!

Comment: Why is everyone mad on this site, just help me don't get pissed at me, I have given the whole code now

Comment: @Zeeshan No one is mad, they're giving you advice on posting better questions in the future so that you can get the help you need with less frustration.

Comment: @Zeeshan - Noone is mad. For future reference: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, I will keep this in mind, thanks everyone for your help, I hope the smile cheered you up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never set the value of your strings.
PAPER = "PAPER"

Also consider using an enumeration and using else if in your code.

Comment: definitive answer here! (although this could have been solved by debugging it... ) to expand, you are not hitting any of your statements because you are comparing player input to nothing

Comment: Ok, I will change this

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works now

Comment: You're welcome. But have a look at the other response as it states another mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Problem may be here. You assigning instead of concatenating in Console.WriteLine

```
 if (playerChoice == STONE && compChoice == PAPER)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(name = "WINS AS STONE BEATS PAPER");
 }
```

But the idea of computating winner through the bunch of if statements is generally bad

Comment: While that code is a problem, it's almost certainly not the cause of the overall issue.

Comment: This is only *one* of probably *many* problems.

Comment: I'm surprised and disappointed that C# allows assignment expressions. They were a frequent cause of bugs in C/C++.

Comment: @buffjape How else can you do `a = b = c = 5`?

Comment: I have fixed this issue too, thank you very much

Comment: Strangely enough @Rotem i never want or need to do multiple assignments :-)

Comment: @buffjape Assignment expressions in C# won't lead to bugs as easily as it might in C/C++. `if(x = 4)` won't compile, as an integer won't work in the place of a boolean and you'll get a compile error telling you as much.

Comment: Very grateful for the strong typing in C# Jonothan, just disappointed that they left this in. Thought they had been more careful.